# How to edit a navigation menu item title while the DrawerLayout is open on Android

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

On Android, when a `NavigationView` is created in a `DrawerLayout`, the title of individual `MenuItems` can be modified by 1) getting handles for the `MenuItems` in the main activity:

```
// Get a handle for the navigation view.
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);

// Get handles for the navigation menu items.
final Menu navigationMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
final MenuItem navigationFirstMenuItem = navigationMenu.getItem(0);
final MenuItem navigationSecondMenuItem = navigationMenu.getItem(1);
final MenuItem navigationThirdMenuItem = navigationMenu.getItem(2);
```

and 2) modifying the titles of the menu items when the drawer is opened using a `DrawerListener`:

```
// The drawer listener is used to update the navigation menu.
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        if ((newState == DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING) || (newState == DrawerLayout.STATE_DRAGGING)) {  // A drawer is opening or closing.
            // Update the title of the menu items.
            navigationFirstMenuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.newString));
            navigationSecondMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
            navigationThirdMenuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.title) + " - " + counterInt);
            }
        }
    });
```

However, once the drawer is open, attempting to change the title of one of the menu items from a part of the main activity running on a different thread results in the following error, which crashes the app:

```
W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

For example, this error can be produced by attempting to update a navigation menu item from inside `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()` as follows:

```
// Get a handle for the WebView.
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

// Set a WebViewClient.
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url){
        navigationFirstMenuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.newString));
        navigationSecondMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
        navigationThirdMenuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.title) + " - " + counterInt);
    }
}
```

The question is how to update a menu item, for example, having a counter that increments in one of the titles, while the navigation drawer is open and the event that needs to update the menu item is running on a different thread.

Comment: How exactly are you "attempting to change the title of one of the menu items from the main activity"?

Comment: By running the same commands that are listed under `onDrawerStateChanged()`.  For example, `navigationThirdMenuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.title) + " - " + counterInt);`

Comment: We need more context. The Exception message implies that you're calling that from a separate thread; e.g., from an `AsyncTask`, a `Timer`, etc.

Comment: It is being called from the Looper thread as part of `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Looper thread", exactly. Every thread can have its own `Looper`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Android's WebView has a looper thread that processes all of the WebView activity, including that contained in `WebViewClient`.  The first WebView instantiated names its looper thread `Looper`.  I have updated the original description to specify that the menu item needs to be updated form a different thread.  Exactly why or from what thread doesn't matter.

Comment: Try to call your code inside a Handler with main looper to run your code on UI thread

Comment: Use the `Activity#runOnUiThread()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. `Activity.runOnUiThread()` solves the problem.  Thank you.  If you would like to post an answer I will accept it.  Otherwise, I will post an answer with a complete set of code.

Comment: Honestly, the actual question here – which is only alluded to in the very last sentence, btw; the rest is rather irrelevant – is a mega-duplicate, and has been addressed here many, many times. I would just close it as such. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Comment: I would prefer not to.  I spent a fair amount searching for this answer without being led in the right direction.  And even you, who is apparently quite familiar with the problem, wasn't able to suggest the correct answer until after asking several questions.  Therefore, I think there is some value in leaving it.

Comment: I had to ask questions because your post is (still) lacking a [mcve]. In fact, the original question had nothing relevant to the actual problem in it, other than the Exception, which is pretty self-explanatory, btw, and easily searchable. Your answer adds nothing to the hundreds of answers here already that demonstrate how to use `runOnUiThread()`, so don't be surprised if somebody comes along and closes this as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: The problem with most technical documentation is that it is organized as a list of all the available commands in a particular section.  For example, "these are all the methods of the Activity class."  This is useful if you want to know everything that can be accomplished from the Activity class.  But to be truly useful, documentation needs to be organized from the perspective of "This is what I want to accomplish, how do I do that?"  That is why this isn't a simple duplicate question, even if the solution may be common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @MikeM., the solution to the problem is to use `Activity.runOnUiThread()` to update the navigation from the same thread that created it.  Specifically, the following code works for me.

```
// Get a handle for the activity.  This is used to update the menu item titles while the navigation menu is open.
Activity activity = this;

// Get a handle for the WebView.
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

// Set a WebViewClient.
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url){
        // Update the menu items' titles from the UI thread.
        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            navigationFirstMenuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.newString));
            navigationSecondMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
            navigationThirdMenuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.title) + " - " + counterInt);
        });
    }
}
```

The key to understanding this problem is that the navigation view is created by the UI thread.  That seems obvious in hindsight, but the error message doesn't specifically state that, and the behavior had initially led me to believe that there was some dedicated `DrawerLayout` thread that could only be accessed via the `DrawerLayout` listener.